# apply used with a tuple does not work

Tags: scala, tuples

I tried to use "spire", a math framework for scala, but I have an unexpected error.Here is my little program:

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.implicits._

trait AbGroup[A] extends Group[A]

final class Rationnel_Quadratique(val n1: Int = 2)(val coef: (Int, Int)) {
override def toString = {
    coef match {
        case (c, i) =>
            s"$c + $i√$n"
    }
}

def a() = coef._1

def b() = coef._2

def n() = n1


}

object Rationnel_Quadratique {

def apply(coef: (Int, Int),n: Int = 2) {
    new Rationnel_Quadratique(n)(coef)
}


}

object AbGroup {

implicit object RQAbGroup extends AbGroup[Rationnel_Quadratique] {
    def +(a: Rationnel_Quadratique, b: Rationnel_Quadratique): Rationnel_Quadratique = Rationnel_Quadratique(coef=(a.a() + b.a(), a.b() + b.b()))   <---

    def inverse(a: Rationnel_Quadratique): Rationnel_Quadratique = Rationnel_Quadratique((-a.a(), -a.b()))

    def id: Int = Rationnel_Quadratique((0, 0))
}

}


object euler66_2 extends App {

println("salut")

val a = r"10/7"
val b = r"5/12"
println(a / b)

val c = Rationnel_Quadratique(1, 2)
val d = Rationnel_Quadratique(3, 4)
val e = c + d
println(e)


}
```

the error relies not on maths but on the apply method : in the line with the arrow the compiler does not allow the use of tuple :

type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Rationnel_Quadratique
        def +(a: Rationnel_Quadratique, b: Rationnel_Quadratique): Rationnel_Quadratique = Rationnel_Quadratique(coef=
                                                                                                                ^

I would rather not use maps.can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the `apply` method on the `Rationnel_Quadratique` companion to return `Unit`.  Change the `apply` definition to:

```
def apply(coef: (Int, Int),n: Int = 2) = {
  new Rationnel_Quadratique(n)(coef)
}
```

Adding the `=` sign will make sure the `apply` method has a return type.

Comment: thanks, it solved this problem.But I have another one: "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spire.algebra.AdditiveSemigroup[Rationnel_Quadratique]
    val e = c + d", located at the line "val = c + d"; but it seems to be linked to spire...